# Copying from one HashMap to another without using putAll()

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I am trying to copy all my data from an old HashMap to a new one after I resize it.

Right now, M = 10, so when the mapSize is 2*M it will double the amount of buckets.

I got the doubling thing down, and it works I checked.

I am just wondering how to move the data from the first "Original" HashMap to the second without creating another Hashmap.

I Have to keep uniform distribution which means I cannot just add more, I need to re-Hash the entries already given.

Any Suggestions on how to do that in my `resizeIfNeedBe()` method?

```
//K = type of keys
//V = type of values
public class SCHashMap<K, V> 
{
    private LinkedList<KVP<K,V>> [] buckets;
    private int mapSize;


    public SCHashMap(int M)
    {
        buckets = (LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>[]) new LinkedList[M];
        for(int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
        {
            buckets[i] = new LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>();
        }
    }

    public void resizeIfNeedBe()
    {
        if (buckets.length * 2 <= mapSize) 
        {
            // need more buckets
            buckets = (LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>[]) new LinkedList[buckets.length* 2];

            //Making it so they aren't all Null
            for(int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
            {
                buckets[i] = new LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>();
            }

        }

    }

    public int bucketSize(int num)
    {
        return buckets[num].size();
    }

    private int bucket(K key)
    {
        return Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % buckets.length;
    }

    public void put(K key, V value)
    {
        resizeIfNeedBe();
        int b = bucket(key);
        for(KVP<K,V> pair : buckets[b])
        {
            if(pair.getKey().equals(key))
            {
                pair.setValue(value);
                return;
            }
        }
        buckets[b].addFirst(new KVP<>(key,value));
        mapSize++;
    }

    public V get(K key)
    {
        int b = bucket(key);
        for(KVP<K,V> pair : buckets[b])
        {
            if(pair.getKey().equals(key))
            {
                return pair.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return mapSize;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wait, what?  Just using `put` on each entry should maintain all the important hash map invariants without any special work.

Comment: I thought it would too, because once it finished the 'resizeIfNeedBe()' it would go right back to the put, the problem is that it will put all of the information needed in, then when it realizes it is too large, it will resize, and set everything back to zero, and start from where it ended, not from the beginning. @LouisWasserman

Comment: Ah.  So your problem is that you need the `resizeIfNeedBe` to preserve the old data rather than just dumping it out.  Why don't you change `resizeIfNeedBe` to temporarily keep a reference to the old buckets array, and then to iterate through it and copy everything over into the new array?

Comment: Yes,, that's exactly what I need to do, unfortunately I just cannot figure out the code to get that done. I need to keep the reference to the old buckets, then iterate through them again after it has been resized using the 'put' method to put them into the new hashmap, to ensure uniform distribution. @LouisWasserman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need `resizeIfNeedBe` to preserve the old entries, that's all.  I might do that like so:

```
          // need more buckets
        LinkedList<KVP<K, V>> oldBuckets = buckets;
        buckets = (LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>[]) new LinkedList[buckets.length* 2];

        //Making it so they aren't all Null
        for(int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
        {
            buckets[i] = new LinkedList<KVP<K, V>>();
        }

        // we know there are no duplicates so we can put things back in easily
        for (int i = 0; i < oldBuckets.length; i++) {
            for (KVP<K, V> entry : oldBuckets[i]) {
               buckets[bucket(entry.getKey())].add(entry);
            }
        }
```